# Configure OpenSCEP to grant certificate requests automatically

Tags: ssl, configuration, network-protocols, openscep

I am trying to setup an OpenSCEP server that can grant certificates automatically instead of me running scepgrant command every time there is a new  request? Can someone let me know how to proceed with the configuration?

Comment: Just wondering if this is a good idea... Isn't some ID verification to bind the actual requester to the certificate the purpose of having to grant certificate request, in turn a key requirement for the security aspect for which PKIs are used?

Comment: I know this is not a good idea, what I am trying to do is automate some of the certificate enrollment tests. It would be great to have openscep grant certificate requests automatically.

Comment: @skokal01 can you tell me how to setup openSCEP in linux?